# Buttons in layout inflater not all the same size

Tags: android, android-layout, button, layout-inflater

I am using inflate to for an activity in android.  All the information I retrieve from my db is correct, however for some reason the buttons width do no appear to be the same size and I cannot figure out why?  This is a layout inflater so the more data is gets from the db the more buttons lines that have two textviews and a button

Here is the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/visitorNotLeft"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/names"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/companies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timeOut"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/appsignout_button"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: there is only one button I can see ?

Comment: which companent you want to same sizE?

Comment: Since this is a layout inflater, for every entry in the DB there is one line with two textviews and one button

Comment: you want to do same width or same height?

Comment: Height isn't a problem, width is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/visitorNotLeft"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" --you can change this to fill_parent
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/names"
        android:layout_width="0dp"  --you can change this to 0dp
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/companies"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timeOut"
        android:layout_width="0dp"  --you can change this to 0dp
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/appsignout_button"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to change the width for everything inside my table row to 0dp

Answer (score 0):

Your width is `wrap_content` which means that they will stretch to fit the content. So, if you have a long string of text in one `Button`, it will be larger.

Also, when using layout weights, you have to set either the width or the height to zero, depending on orientation. Have a look at the example from docs:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/message" />
```

The height is set to zero :)

Comment: When I changed the size of the layout_width, I still get buttons in each row that are different size width.